# How to Delete row using context menu?

Tags: android, database, listview, contextmenu

How can I delete a list item and get an updated list using `onContextItemSelected`?

How can I delete a row using context menu?

Code:

```
case R.id.Delete_Note:
            Database_Notepad db=new Database_Notepad(Create_Task.this);
            db.DeleteNote();

            break;
```

My Database:

```
public void DeleteNote(int rowId) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            db.delete(Table_Notepad, Col_ID + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(rowId) });
            db.close();
        }
```

How can I update my listview after the deletion of an item?

This is how I'm setting data to listview:

```
Database_Notepad db = new Database_Notepad(Create_Task.this); Cursor c = db.Get_All_Note(); 
String[] from = new String[] {Database_Notepad.Col_File_Name,Database_Notepad.Col_Due_Date}; 
int[] to = new int[] {R.id.titlename, R.id.duedatetext}; 
SimpleCursorAdapter madapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(Create_Task.this, R.layout.file_row, c, from, to); 
 this.setListAdapter(madapter); 
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this); 
registerForContextMenu(getListView()); 
db.close();
```

Comment: what is your problem, is the row not deleting from database? or else it is not updating on the listview

Comment: It is not updating the listview???

Comment: So post the code of your Adapter class and how you set it to your ListView. Because the code of database will not help to answer your question.

Comment: deleting the row in database working in normal click events ?

Comment: I have done with row deletion my question was deleting the row. But I have done with that. Thanks

Comment: Yes I got it. But now I want to update my list in listview.???

Comment: Update the data source(ie data list or array) with the new database changes given to your Adapter and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); This will update your listView with new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229837/how-to-delete-row-using-context-menu/14230134#comment19740522_14229837) you success to delete the row item, but you failed to update your listview,

So whenever some changes made in listview data you should notify your adater by applying [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) like this `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` ,it will reflect in your listview if some items get added or deleted.

*hope it works!*

Comment: Hi, Yes I am trying to do the same but it is giving error, null pointer exception and force close.

Comment: @Shweta where? what? When?

Comment: Database_Notepad db = new Database_Notepad(Create_Task.this);

  Cursor c = db.Get_All_Note();
  
  String[] from = new String[] {Database_Notepad.Col_File_Name, Database_Notepad.Col_Due_Date};
  int[] to = new int[] {R.id.titlename, R.id.duedatetext};

  SimpleCursorAdapter madapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(Create_Task.this, R.layout.file_row, c, from, to);

  this.setListAdapter(madapter);
  
  getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
  
  registerForContextMenu(getListView());
  
  db.close();

Comment: I have used simpleCursorAdapter and Listview is not updating using adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Database_Notepad db = new Database_Notepad(Create_Task.this); Cursor c = db.Get_All_Note(); String[] from = new String[] {Database_Notepad.Col_File_Name, Database_Notepad.Col_Due_Date}; int[] to = new int[] {R.id.titlename, R.id.duedatetext}; SimpleCursorAdapter madapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(Create_Task.this, R.layout.file_row, c, from, to); this.setListAdapter(madapter); getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this); registerForContextMenu(getListView()); db.close();

Comment: @Shweta while deleting the item you have call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), else try this adapter.changeCursor(myCursor).

Comment: Yes. list is updating using adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); , but getting error, nullpointerexception and force close.

Comment: where? on which line? best to do debug and trace it.

Comment: Hi, Its done, i have added my simplecursoradapter in a method and put that method after deleting the item.